# Pass Model Field Value Via a URL in Django Using FormView

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have two different views that work together.  A Formview and a ListView.  They are working fine.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form method="GET" autocomplete=off action="{% url 'Book:book_by_name_list' %}">

  <div>
    {{ form.dropdown }}
  </div>

   <button type="submit" class="button1">Submit</h3></div></button>

</form>
```

Here is my FormView:

```
class BookByNameView(LoginRequiredMixin,FormView):
    form_class = BookByNameForm
    template_name = 'book_by_name.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(BookByNameView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

Here is my Form:

```
class BookByNameForm(forms.Form):

    dropdown = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Book.objects.none(),required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        dropdown = kwargs.pop('dropdown', None)
        super(BookByNameForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['dropdown'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'choices6'
        qs = Book.objects.all()
        self.fields['dropdown'].queryset = qs
```

Here is the URL that I am using:

```
url(r'^book_by_name_list/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.BookByNameListView.as_view(),name='book_by_name_list'),
```

When the user clicks on the form.dropdown, view and clicks submit, the book_by_name_list URL is returned via the following ListView:

```
class BookByNameListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'book_list'
    template_name = 'book_by_name_list.html'
    paginate_by = 15

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(BookByNameListView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BookByNameListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        dropdown = self.request.GET.get("dropdown", None)
        context['dropdown'] = dropdown
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        dropdown = self.request.GET.get("dropdown", None)
        user = self.request.user
        if dropdown:
            queryset = Book.objects.filter(Q(id__exact=dropdown)).distinct()
        else:
            queryset = Book.objects.none()
        return queryset
```

Using the code above the dropdown is retrieved via the HTML GET and the ID of the dropdown is returned.   I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to capture the publisher of the book instead of the ID.  Somehow get a different field of the model based on the book the end user selects.  Currently I'm using a URL that is getting the PK of the book and that is working.  Is there someway to capture the dropdown ID of the book and in return the publisher field instead of the ID?  I don't want to use sessions, I am trying to figure out how to get the ID and then use it to get the publisher.  Use HTML Post instead?  I'm doing something similar in a different view but it's in a detail view so it's easier to get the attributes in that particular view.  I'm stumped.  Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: Will a simple query to the database in BookByNameListView not give you the publisher ? assuming publisher is a filed in Book model.

Comment: @Neeraj Unfortunately no.  My example is pretty elementary....but I need to figure out a way to get a field value so that I can use it in a different way.  Unforutnately there's no way for me to make Publisher a foreignkey in this case.

Comment: dropdown field in BookByNameForm can be changed to a ChoiceField and then define a list of tuples ('publisher name', 'book name') , when a user selects a book , you will receive name of the publisher.

Comment: I figured out a solution.  I essentially created a key for book publisher so that I can then just query the key.  Just took a bit of thinking and tracing.  Thanks for the help!